# Microsoft TFS dashboard widget fail to load

Tags: tfs, widget, dashboard, tfs-web-access

Hello guys I need some help.

I'm trying to create a very simple Microsoft TFS dashboard widget which displays hello world but every time I go into the dashboard my widget will fail to load.

I'm attaching 3 pictures 
 1. [My simple HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6WFT.png)
 2. [How my projekt is filed and setup in my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BspKx.png)
 3. [A picture of the widget dashboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X49Rr.png)

I really hope someone can help me, I have been struggling for two days now.

Comment: [No noises in post please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Don't post text as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to be very specific with your JavaScript code. The javascriptcode defines everting in a widget.

Comment: I will do that.